# SDL2 DestroyRenderer SEGFAULT

Tags: c, sdl-2

I came up with a minimal exemple of my program throwing a SEGFAULT on call to `SDL_DestroyRenderer(SDL_Renderer* renderer);`

```
int Setup(t_game* game)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Init SDL");
        return 0;
    }

    game->window = SDL_CreateWindow("Client",
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                    SCREEN_X,
                                    SCREEN_Y,
                                    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    game->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(game->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game->renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    return 1;
}

void Cleanup(t_game* game)
{  
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(game->renderer);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(game->window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Loop(t_game* game)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    int loop = 1;
    while (loop)
    {
        SDL_RenderClear(game->renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(game->renderer);
        loop = EventHandler(&event, game);
    }
}
```

Functions are called from the main as such:

```
int main()
{
    t_game game;
    Setup(&game);
    Loop(&game);
    Cleanup(&game);
    return 0;
}
```

And the game struct is declared like:

```
typedef struct s_game
{
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Window* window;
} t_game;
```

In the cleanup I get a SEGFAULT saying invalid free

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ae1f9c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ae1f9c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00005555555554d0 in Cleanup (game=0x7fffffffdd90)
#2  0x00005555555555e9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdea8)
```

However in gdb after setting breakpoints in all 3 functions I always have the same pointer for the renderer.

**Update 1:**
If I put all three functions together I do not have the error anymore.
**Update 2:**

```
int EventHandler(SDL_Event* event, t_game* game)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event->type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                return 0;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch (event->key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        return 0;
                }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I see no problem in presented code, and your example works just fine, so either it is not-so-minimal (i.e. critical parts are omitted) or problem is elsewhere. Are there other threads? Why there are no file names in backtrace, is your program compiled without debugging symbols? If so, why, they are exactly to ease debugging.

Comment: Try calling `EventHandler` at the beginning of the loop (handling all the messaged before first present may be important). Also what is this `EventHandler`?

Comment: I removed the filenames from the trace as I thought they would be irrelevant. Compiling and running this exact program gives me the error I described. EventHandler is a simple SDL_Poll while loop looking for the escape key (I don't see why it could matter as it does not change the renderer, game argument is not used in this function)

Comment: @2A-66-42 what does it mean "if you put all three functions together"? Was they in separate files? Do you have function declarations? Are there any warnings if you compile with `-Wall`?

Comment: I mean creating one function with the code of the three functions inside. I have only one file and no warning with `-Wall`.

Comment: What's in `EventHandler`?

Comment: @2A-66-42 great, now you should merge all your pieces into single block of code that is minimal and complete (i.e. can be copied into text editor and compiled without any modification - and of course you yourself should verify that problem persists after that), so we can be sure you're not omitting critical parts. As it stands now, there is nothing wrong with given code.

Comment: I agree that the example code could be more succint, but that's way shorter than some other program I've seen here. I have a feeling you're doing something in `EventHandler` that you shouldn't. Again, can you post the code of this function?

Comment: After Update 2 : Wow, okay. I thought you might have slipped a SDL_Quit() in the EventHandler, but I can see that's not the case. I see nothing obviously wrong with your code. Can you check you're compiling and linking against the same SDL2 version? I see you're linked to SDL2-2.0, but are you using the SDL2 2.0.8 headers?

Comment: No idea what happened but I disabled hugepages and now it works without errors.

Comment: Good that you found your problem! You might want to report it to the SDL team. You can write this as an answer and accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that hugepages interferes with SDL2 in some way as disabling it solved the invalid free error.